# Always display Comment field

Tags: column

I have a Comment field (multi-line plain text; append changes) on a SharePoint list.  In "All Items" view it displays the Comment field with comments. However, for some items that has no comments I want it to display its previous comment. Out-of-the-box it can't be done but maybe you have some ideas?  I'm using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just so happens I did a blog post on how to do this with a DVWP about a week ago: http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/07/showing-all-versions-of-append-changes-to-existing-text-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp/